# UITableView doesn't scroll when I add it as subview

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, subview

In iOS / Swift, I just add `UITableView` programmatically to a custom view, like this (part of code):

```
class CustomView: UIView: UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

    ...
}

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    ...

    let customView: CustomView = CustomView()
    var tableView: UITableView = UITableView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 200, height: 200))

    override func viewDidLoad() {

        customView.addSubview(tableView)
        view.addSubview(customView)
    }
}
```

I can see my table view, with data... it isn't scrolling. Even with `userInteractionEnabled` set to `true`.

Can someone help me ?

Comment: You didn't constrain the tableView or give it a size.. Also "TableView" is not a class I recognize. It should be "UITableView".

Comment: Sorry about that it isn't a copy / paste code. But I gave it a size for sure.

Comment: What's in `CustomView`?

Comment: There is the entire tableview delegate and data source methods + registerNib for UITabelViewCell

Comment: Did you try to enable `userInteractionEnabled` for your `customView` too? Also try to enable `isScrollEnabled` in your `tableView`.

Comment: yes I did that.

Comment: I also try to add `scrollEnabled` to tableView without any success :(